# WORDPRESS: Trying to follow steps in a tutorial but Fatal Error warning pops up

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, fatal-error, meta-boxes

### ==ISSUES HAVE BEEN SOLVED==

I am trying to follow the steps within this tutorial//

http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-wordpress-custom-post-types-to-add-events-to-your-site/

But I've come across a `Fatal Error` after step 2.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function format_date() in /functions.php on line 134`

**Error Line//**
`echo format_date($custom["event_date"][0]) . '<br /><em>' .`

**Content currently in Functions.php//**
http://pastebin.com/FvqvE187

What exactly is the issue?
&How can I fix this?

## EDIT//

Added 
`function format_date($unixtime) {
return date("F", $unixtime)." ".date("d", $unixtime).", ".date("Y", $unixtime);
}`
to my functions.php to fix the `Fatal Error` another issue occurred.

Before the error,  in the post edit screen there was a `Event Detail` Metabox. But after this change the box isn't there any more. It allowed me to add Locations and Times ect. Now I have no way to add this extra information. 
It's clear the new code caused this but why?

## EDIT2//

The answer to my 1st edit was simply adding the rest of the code (input boxes ect)
After adding the rest of the code this error pops up within the `Event Detail` metabox.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function format_date() in /functions.php on line 172`

This is line `172`//

```
$ret = '<p><label>Date: </label><input type="text" name="event_date" value="' . format_date(get_event_field("event_date")) . '" /><em>(mm/dd/yyy)</em>';
```

## EDIT3//

All I had to do was remove `format_date` from line `172` and also remove one of the parentheses at the end. Doing that enables the Event Details again :)

Comment: The function is not defined. Look at this comment: http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-wordpress-custom-post-types-to-add-events-to-your-site/#comment-6010

Comment: @martinCzerwi I've tried adding that code already, another error just pops up.

Comment: @martinCzerwi It works now -_- I guess I placed that set of code in the wrong place but yet it says "place anywhere in functions.php" I added it to the way bottom at first. Moved it at the top `events_custom_columns($column){ global $post;` function and now it works.

Comment: @martinCzerwi I've come across another issue, please check updated question...

Comment: @martinCzerwi Mind checking out the econd Edit please?

Comment: The error message says it all, function format_date not defined. To make it easier, could you please update your pastebin post with your current code and please state if the code on pastebin is the (full) functions.php?

Comment: I fixed the errors :) Thank you though! @martinCzerwi

Comment: That's OK. Hope you got it all going. What's a bit disappointing, is that you just removed the function and all function calls to `format_date`. That might be a quick solution, but isn't a real fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the 1st `Fatal Error`//

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function format_date() in /functions.php on line 134`

Adding

`function format_date($unixtime) {
return date("F", $unixtime)." ".date("d", $unixtime).", ".date("Y", $unixtime);
}`

at the top of this code//

```
function events_custom_columns($column){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom();

switch ($column) {
case "event_date":
        echo format_date($custom["event_date"][0]) . '<br /><em>' .
        $custom["event_start_time"][0] . ' - ' .
        $custom["event_end_time"][0] . '</em>';
        break;

case "event_location":
        echo $custom["event_location"][0];
        break;

case "event_city":
        echo $custom["event_city"][0];
        break;
}
}
```

**NOTE://** For some reason I am not sure of adding the code to the bottom didn't work for me.

**Next Edit//** 
Answer to this `Fatal Error`//

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function format_date() in /functions.php on line 172`

on this line//

`$ret = '<p><label>Date: </label><input type="text" name="event_date" value="' . format_date(get_event_field("event_date")) . '" /><em>(mm/dd/yyy)</em>';`

Simply remove `format_date` text and ONE parentheses from `(event_date"))`.

Now the Event Details are available :)

Answer (score 0):

function format_date($unixtime) { } is already define above check this function